# Trying to enable USB interface for Wireless Adapter Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, usb, realtek-wireless

I am trying to setup a wireless USB adapter on my machine and I am currently lost. I believe I installed the driver correctly based on my `lsusb` info below:

```
BUS 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:818b Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

However when I run `ifconfig` I do not see my wireless interface.
But for some reason when I run `ifconfig -a` I am able to see the new interface but it appears with `Link encap:Ethernet`:

`ifconfig -a` output:

[image]

In addition when I run `lshw -C network` it claims `USB:0 Disabled`.

`lshw` output:

[image]

I am relatively new to Ubuntu but I think I need to enable the USB in order for my adapter to work. How can I do this? Is their an alternative solution?

Lastly my wireless extention appears when I run `iwconfig`. I would post a screenshot but my reputation is not high enough for more than 2 links.

Answer (score 0):

The middle item on your ifconfig output is your wireless adapter, it shows as the 'Logical name' section of your lshw  output.

Can you try running :

sudo ifconfig enx68ca0001030a up

Comment: now when I issue the ifconfig command the 'Logical name'  of my adapter appears and the USB is no longer disabled however I still do not have internet access.

Comment: Just bringing the interface up, does not invoke the "assign IP-number and set up routing information (perhaps by getting them from the DHCP-server)"